# On clicking submit button server-side php code is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, formvalidation-plugin

I have created a SignUp page with HTML,CSS AND BOOTSTRAP....For Validation i've used javascript and php for database connectivity....when i submit the form it only validates but not refelecting in the database...To be exact when i click submit button It just validates and not reflecting in Mysql?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sign Up Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    </div>
    <form class="form" id="form" onsubmit="javascript.js" action="insert.php" method="POST">
        <div class="form-control">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Imran010" id="username" name="username">
            <small>Error Message</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label>email</label>
            <input type="Email" placeholder="Imran010@abc.com" id="email" name="email">
            <small>Error Message</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="Password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password">
            <small>Error Message</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label>Check Password</label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password Check" id="password2" name="password2">
            <small>Error Message</small>
        </div>
        <button id="Submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: The onsubmit="javascript.js" inside the form tag is supposed to call a function inside your Javascript that is validating the data. Not the file. Are you able to share your JS Code? And your php if possible.